# How to convert form to class?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WC W1 = WC.CreateWindow("", "");
        }
    }
}
```

WindowControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class WC
{
    public static Form CreateWindow(string name, string title)
    {
        Form nform = new Form();
        nform.Name = name;
        nform.Text = title;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(nform);
        return nform;
    }
    public static void DeleteWindow(Form name)
    {
        name.Close();
    }
```

}

But I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'WC'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Form W1 = WC.CreateWindow("", "");` or `var W1 = WC.CreateWindow("", "");` or just `WC.CreateWindow("", "");` since you're not using the variable anyway.

Comment: `WC.CreateWindow` returns *Form* not *WC*.  So Change it as `Form W1 = WC.CreateWindow("", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do something strange. If you trying create something similar to form factory, you can do it like this:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Form W1 = WC.CreateWindow("test1", "....");
            var W2 = WC.CreateWindow("test2", "....");
        }
    }
}
```